# Accessing random image pixels using a for loop

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, coredump

I am trying to learn image processing using *OpenCV*. I wrote some code to edit an image. The edits are working well except for changing the color of some pixels.

I am trying to access some random pixels, and change their color (that is when `status == 3`). When I run the program I get `"[run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`, which I think means that there is a denied memory access.

```
  int main( ) {
      Mat originalImage = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); 
      if (originalImage.empty()){ 
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;         
          return -1;
      } 
      int orgRows = originalImage.rows; 
      int orgCols = originalImage.cols;    
      int status; // output indicator

      cout << "Please select the settings" << endl; 
      cin >> status;   
      Mat displayedImage;  
      while (status != 0 ) {
          if(status == 1){
              // some code
          }
          else if (status == 2 ){   
              // some code  
          }else if (status == 3 ){
              int j;
              int k;            
              for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                  j = rand()% orgCols;
                  k = rand() % orgRows;
                  Vec3b intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);  
                  intensity[0] = 255;
                  intensity[1] = 255;
                  intensity[2] = 255;               
               }
               displayedImage = originalImage;
           }else if (status == 4){ 
               // some code
           }else if (status == 5 ){
               // some code
           }else{  
               // some code
           }
           namedWindow("MyWindow",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
           imshow("MyWindow", displayedImage); 
           waitKey(1000);  
           destroyWindow("MyWindow");
           cout << "Continue ? ... Please select the settings" << endl; 
           cin >> status; 
      } 
  return 0;
}
```

### Question:

What is causing the error and how could it be solved?

Comment: You must inform the line that causes the crash for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems, both on this line:

```
Vec3b intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);
```

1. Matrices are accessed as (row, col), not (x, y). So you need to use: `Vec3b intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);`
2. You are *copying* the pixel bgr value. Every change you do on `intensity` won't be reflected in `originalImage`. You can easily correct this using a reference to the data in `originalImage`: `Vec3b& intensity = ...`.

As a result, you need to change the mentioned line to:

```
Vec3b& intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(k, j);
```

Note: Using `intensity[0] = 255;` works ok. You don't need to use `intensity.val[0] = 255;`

---

Note that there are some improvements that you can do.

1) Since you work on `Vec3b` type, you make the assumption that your image is read as `CV_8UC3`, i.e. a 3 channel matrix, 8 bit depth per channel. So, if you load a 16bit image, or a single channel (grayscale) image, or an image with alpha channel (RGBA) your program will crash. You can enforce that you need a `CV_8UC3` image while loading the image like:

```
Mat3b originalImage = imread("image.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Now you can access the pixels value without the `at<>`, since the image type is fixed. So you can do:

```
Vec3b& intensity = originalImage(k, j);
```

2) You can simply assign a new value to `originalImage`, like:

```
originalImage.at<Vec3b>(k,j) = Vec3b(255,255,255); 
//or
originalImage(k,j) = Vec3b(255,255,255); // If originalImage is a Mat3b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Now its working. You can't allocate a new pixel value by writing "intensity[0]" you have to use it with "intensity.val[0]" or "`originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[0] = 255;`"

```
  #include <opencv\cv.h>
#include<highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main( ) {

  Mat originalImage = imread("p001.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); 

  if (originalImage.empty()){ 
    cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;         
    return -1;
  } 
  int orgRows = originalImage.rows; 
  int orgCols = originalImage.cols;    
  int status; // output indicator
  cout << "Please select the settings" << endl; 
  cin >> status;   
  Mat displayedImage;  
    while (status != 0 ) {
        if(status == 1){
            // some code
        }
    else if (status == 2 ){   
            // some code  
        }else if (status == 3 ){
            int j=0;
            int k=0;          
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                j = rand()% orgCols;
                k = rand() % orgRows;

               // Vec3b intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);  

                originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[0] = 255;
                originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[1] = 255;
                originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[2] = 255;
                /*intensity[0] = 255;
                intensity[1] = 255;
                intensity[2] = 255;     */            
        }
        displayedImage = originalImage;
        }else if (status == 4){ 
          // some code
        }else if (status == 5 ){
            // some code
        }else{  
        // some code
        }
        namedWindow("MyWindow",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("MyWindow", displayedImage); 
        waitKey(1000);  
        destroyWindow("MyWindow");
        cout << "Continue ? ... Please select the settings" << endl; 
        cin >> status; 
    }   
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what was the error and how did you solve it?

Comment: @Miki intensity[0] = 255 the problem was with this statement while he was trying to access pixel. th

Comment: I got that, what I meant is that you should edit the explanation in your answer. Code only answer are difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @Miki yeah i got !! i ll keep that in mind before answering :)

Comment: You can use the _edit_ link at the bottom of your answer to add some content

Comment: @Miki  i wrote"intensity.at<uchar>(j,k)" but it's displaying only this ""intensity.at(j,k)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from you `for` loop:

```
Vec3b intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);
-----^  
intensity[0] = 255;
intensity[1] = 255;
intensity[2] = 255;
```

If you want to access (assign new value to) the *RGB* intensities at the random pixel: `(j,k)`, you need to change it to reference of the original object:

```
Vec3b& intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);
```

and use either of the methods for access:

```
intensity[0] = 255;
intensity[1] = 255;
intensity[2] = 255;
```

or

```
originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[0] = 255;
originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[1] = 255;
originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(k,j)[2] = 255;
```

or:

```
Vec3b& intensity = originalImage.at<Vec3b>(j, k);  
intensity.val[0] = 255;
intensity.val[1] = 255;
intensity.val[2] = 255;
```

For further reading, check [opencvexamples](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/assessing-pixel-values-of-image.html) and [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html).

Comment: it is not working using "intensity" (2nd option) .. thanks for the references!

Comment: @H.K you are welcome! I've edited and corrected the answer .