# Editing video frames on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have the following code:

```
# Import packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

X_RESOLUTION = 640
Y_RESOLUTION = 480

# Initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (X_RESOLUTION, Y_RESOLUTION)
camera.framerate = 10
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size = (X_RESOLUTION, Y_RESOLUTION))

# Allow camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

#Capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # Grab the raw NumPy array representing the image
    image = frame.array

    # Show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # Clear the stream so it is ready to receive the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # If the 'q' key was pressed, break from the loop
    if(key == ord('q')):
        break
```

It is all fine and dandy. It captures video and displays it on my screen and it exits when I press 'q'. However, if I wanted to manipulate the frames somehow, say for example I wanted to set every pixels R value in each frame to 255 to make the image red. How would I do that?

My end goal is to write software that detects movement on a static background.  I understand the theory and the actual data manipulation that needs to be done to make this happen, I just cant figure out how to access each frame's pixel data and operate on it. I attempted to change some values in 'image', but it says the array is immutable and cannot be written to, only read from.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed each pixel{R,G,B values accessed separately } value randomly and have changed the value of it in the image. You can do it on an video by extracting each frame of it. It is implemented in c++ with opencv. Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664968/3853072 you will get an idea.